# How should a follow "queue" on iOS with AFNetworking/NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsurlconnection

I have the following implementation in my app:
- A list of topics to follow using their ids.
- A system which retries connections when they fail due to internet dropping/server failure.

Let's say a user taps 3 follow buttons very fast.
For each of the taps a NSURLConnection is started to assign to that user that topic
How should this be approached considering the following cases that might occur:

A) All 3 connections fail. All 3 need to be retried, but each has a different parameter - the topic id.
B) Only 2 of the connections fail, the third one succeeds.
C) The first connection fails, but after the user pressed the unfollow button which also fails.

By fail, in this case I mean that a pop-up appears which prompts the user to retry.
This happened because the NSURLConnection received a 404 or timed out.

Comment: That seems to be a very broad question, and not so much a programming problem, but rather design choices...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule, you shouldn't make the user dismiss a popup when a connection fails, but rather should show some indicator in the UI.  After all, there's usually nothing the user can do to fix the connection, and the user wouldn't have asked for the data if he/she didn't want it, so silently retrying as soon as the network comes back is almost invariably the right behavior, making the user's action superfluous.

In every case, start watching for reachability changes, then try again when reachability says that the request might succeed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The pop-up would inform the user, that his internet is down (if it's the case) or that the server is down. The app displays all it's interface based on data downloaded from the server, so if the connection is down there should be no point for the user to be able to use the app.

Comment: My point was that there's no reason for the user to have to dismiss a dialog.  It's an extra tap that provides no real benefit to you or to the user.  If you show that message in a view that slides down below the menu bar, you can slide it right back up when the network comes back, and the user is still informed of the problem without needing to tap on the screen.